# Replace a tag and value in xml using perl one liner

Tags: xml, perl, shell, xml-libxml

I need to replace the date value 2016-11-02 in the date tag with a new value using a perl one liner

```
<header>
            <name>V5 CDS Composites</name>
            <version>1.1a</version>
            <date>2016-11-02</date>

    </header>
```

I can do this using xml libxml but want to do this in the shortest possible way using a perl one liner. I cannot use just 2016-11-02 as there are multiple instances of this with different tags.

I am doing this inside a shell where the tag and the value are inside a variable

Comment: You want to use only `perl` and not any proper `xml` aware tools?

Comment: yes, want to use only perl

Comment: @BRATVADDI `awk -F'<|>' -v newDate="2222-11-00" '/<date>/{gsub(/2016-11-02/,newDate,$3)}1' inputfile` if you are ok with `awk. However, I am not encouraging you to use xml unaware tools.

Comment: *Why* does it have to be a one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following one liner

```
perl -pe 'my $new_date = "2016-12-12"; s/<date>.+/<date>$new_date<\/date>/g' xml.txt
```

Here

```
-p use to iterate the loop on a file and the line gets print after that.

-e for execute the script
```

And there is another switch use to perform the changes in original file. which is `-i` . Then you want to make a copy of original file means the oneliner should be

```
perl -i.copy -pe 'my $new_date = "2016-12-12"; s/<date>.+/<date>$new_date<\/date>/g' xml.txt
```

The file will store into .copy extension.

Comment: was looking for exactly this. needed the double quotes as the shell wouldnt resolve the variable otherwise

Answer (score 2):

Use `perl` *and* an XML aware tool:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -0777 -e '$t=XML::Twig->parse(<>);$_->set_text('2017-01-01') for $t ->get_xpath('.//date');$t->print'
```

Or perhaps:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -0777 -e 'XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers=>{date=>sub{$_->set_text("2017-01-01")}})->parse(<>)->print'
```

(Slightly shorter, depends if that's easier to read or not).

It's technically slightly longer than some of the alternatives here, but it has the benefit of being an *actual* XML parsed solution.

You could also use `parsefile_inplace` instead, to use it 'sed like' on a file. You might also find setting `pretty_print` to be useful, to reformat the XML.

Answer (score 1):

This one liner do the job and save the file before doing the substituion

```
perl -pi.back -e 's~(?=<date>)[\d-]+(?=</date>)~2016-11-18~' file.xml
```